# Spring Integration: int-file:inbound-channel-adapter : filename-pattern

Tags: spring-integration

I need to support multiple filename pattern in int-file:inbound-channel-adapter.
Say i want compressed and uncompressed files both.
Can anybody help in determining how to support multiple extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filename-regex` with a regular expression...

```
filename-regex="^.*\.(txt|zip)$"
```